# jquery dialog calls a server side method with button parameters

Tags: asp.net, jquery, server-side, parameter-passing

I have a gridview control with  delete asp:ImageButton for each row of the grid. What I would like is for a jquery dialog to pop up when a user clicks the delete button to ask if they are sure they want to delete it. 
So far I have the dialog coming up just fine, Ive got buttons on that dialog and I can make the buttons call server side methods but its getting the dialog to know the ID of the row that the user has selected and then passing that to the server side code. 


The button in the page row is currently just an 'a' tag with the id 'dialog_link'. The jquery on the page looks like this:

```
$("button").button();
    $("#DeleteButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ManageUsers.aspx/DeleteUser",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                $("#DeleteButton").text(msg.d);
            }
        });
    });

    // Dialog           
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        bgiframe: true

    });

    // Dialog Link
    $('#dialog_link').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

The dialog itself is just a set of 'div' tags. 
Ive thought of lots of different ways of doing this (parameter passing, session variable etc...) but cant figure out how to get any of them working.
Any ideas are most welcome
As always, thanks in advance to those who contribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently done something exactly the same at work - confirmation of a delete item. I solved it by using the Data http://docs.jquery.com/Data method to store the value I wanted to pass along.

So for example my delete links had the following:

```
<a href="#" class="delete" id="1">Delete</a>
```

Then monitor all clicks on for class "delete", when this happens set the data on the dialog:

```
$("#dialog").data("id", $(this).attr("id"));
```

Which will then be accessible when you're in your dialog.

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Delete': function() {
                alert($(this).data('id'));
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps, shout if it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Alistair, I'm really close now, all I think I need now is to be able to pass the parameter to the server side method. In my AJAX method I use this to register the method url: "ManageUsers.aspx/DeleteUser". Ive tried splitting the string to try and put the parameter in it "ManageUsers.aspx/DeleteUser(" + 
$(this).data('id') +")" but alas to no avail. Any ideas on how to achieve the last piece of the puzzle?

Comment: `$.ajax( { data: $(this).data('id'), complete: /*so on so on*/ });`

Comment: Thanks Gutzofter. Ok, after reading up more about this I see the parameter is passed back as a querystring. As the server side method is static how do I access the querystring object?

Comment: Any clues on this please? I still don't know how to access the sent data in the server side code...

Comment: No worries got it working now thanks. Was all in the way I added to the data section of the ajax call. Changed it to "{\"id\":\"" + $(this).data('title') + "\"}" and it now works :)